# Can't load modules when running bash script through R studio

Tags: linux, bash, rstudio

I'm trying to run a bash script within R studio using R system call system(). It seems that modules cannot be loaded this way.

I googled this problem and apparently scripts executed from R studio will run in a noninteractive bash. I forced this non-interactive bash to source my ~/.bashrc (which contains many lines of "module load" something) through adding `source ~/.bashrc` at the beginning of the bash script. when I run the script in R, however, it still reports that "module" command is not found.

The beginning of the bash script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
while getopts i: option
```

The module loading lines in `.bashrc` looks like this:

```
/usr/share/lmod/lmod/init/bash
PATH=~/local/bin/:$PATH
export PATH
module load bedtools
module load kentUCSC
module load python3
module load python2
```

As you can see in the first line of the .bashrc file, I even added a line to initiate "module" package.

The error in R:

```
/bar/cfan/.bashrc: line 118: module: command not found
/bar/cfan/.bashrc: line 119: module: command not found
/bar/cfan/.bashrc: line 120: module: command not found
/bar/cfan/.bashrc: line 121: module: command not found
/bar/cfan/.bashrc: line 123: module: command not found
/bar/cfan/.bashrc: line 124: module: command not found
/bar/cfan/.bashrc: line 125: module: command not found
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone can give me a hint about what's going on. I really hope I can run bash scripts in R studio. It would make my life much easier.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Can you edit your post to include a relevant portion of your R script showing the `system` call you're making?

Comment: Bash should be OK with `~`, but I would write `PATH="$HOME/local/bin:$PATH`. You also need to show the full scripts or a reduced version that demonstrates the problem. *`line 118: module: command not found`* means a lot of information is missing. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: adding some `echo` and `which` commands to your script might be helpful, e.g. to show the contents of `$PATH` and make sure it's actually running the right things.  I've not used `lmod` before, but I think you should be `source`ing that `lmod/init/bash` file rather than running it

Comment: I have a smilar, it seems that it is an issue due to differences in the environment variables and shell configuration between my interactive shell (where I run from the command line) and the environment in which R Shiny executes the script. But, I don't know how to solve this. Any solutions please share